# All elements push into array despite if (should act as filter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I have a little form in my HTML that takes data for a reservation. The correspondent submit button is associated with a function (`saveReserve`). The idea is that the function could take the data and push it into an array, but also detects when a similar reservation has already been made, and so if it's the case, left the new one out (don't push it into the array with the one that is similar).

The issue is that all reservations are push even if they are the same, ignoring the IF element:

```js
let allReservation = [];
var NR = 0

const saveReserve = () => {
    var date= $("#date").val();    //These are the form inputs//
    var hour= $("#hour").val();
    var gameRes = $("#reserveG").val();
    NR++

   
    var reservation = ({date, hour, gameRes})
    let exist = allReservation.find(e=> e.date == reservation.date && e.hour == reservation.hour && e.gameRes == reservation.gameRes);
    console.log(reservation, exist)
    
    if (exist == undefined) {
        allReservation.push( NR + ": " + $("#nameR").val() + Object.values(reservation) );
        alert ("All good")
    }else{   
      alert ("Invalid, try again")
    }

    //nameR is the name input in the form//


    console.log (allReservation)
    $("input").val('') 
}
$('[type="submit"]').click(saveReserve)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2021-08-05" id="date" />
<input type="number" id="hour" min="0" max="23" value="7" />
<input type="text" id="reserveG" value="A" />
<input type="text" id="nameR" value="B" />
<input type="submit" />
```

```
let allReservation = [];
var NR = 0

const saveReserve = () => {
    var date= $("#date").val();    //These are the form inputs//
    var hour= $("#hour").val();
    var gameRes = $("#reserveG").val();
    NR++

   
    var reservation = ({date, hour, gameRes})
    let exist = allReservation.find(e=> e.date == reservation.date && e.hour == reservation.hour && e.gameRes == reservation.gameRes);
    
    if (exist == undefined) {
        allReservation.push( NR + ": " + $("#nameR").val() + Object.values(reservation) ),
        alert ("All good") )
    }else{   
      alert ("Invalid, try again")
    }

    //nameR is the name input in the form//


    console.log (allReservation)
    $("input").val('') 
}
```

The only way the .find works is if I add this at the end of the function:

```
allReservation.push (reservation)
```

Then it recognise the repeat elements and alerts them, but also push them in.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The .find() detects when a reservation with the same data as the one input in the form is already in the array. The idea is that when it happens, the new reservations that match is ignored and don't get push into the same array, but it doesn't work. At the end I have an array with repetead info

Comment: `reservation` is an object like this: `{ date: "2021-08-05", hour: "7", gameRes: "A" }` whereas you push a string like this to the `allReservations` array: `"1: B2021-08-05,7,A"`. Of course, that's not comparable

Comment: Additionally, remove the comma at the end of the line of `allReservation.push` and the parenthesis at the end of the following line.

Comment: Besides that, the reservation to check doesn't have a `NR` and a `nameR` yet to check

Comment: You _think_ you _do_. But `reservation` in the `array.find()` is clearly an object as declared just in the previous line. Otherwise, you couldn't do `Object.values()` later in the code.

Comment: I see now what you mean, thanks! The thing is I didn't want to compare all of the info that enters in the input, just those three parts. The name and NR CAN be the same, but not the date, hour  and game. I see that in doing that, I end up making two different things, thanks again.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the first comment by shaedrich:

"is an object like this: { date: "2021-08-05", hour: "7", gameRes: "A" } whereas you push a string like this to the allReservations array: "1: B2021-08-05,7,A". Of course, that's not comparable"

So I just put all the data in the same var and push it like that, without the Objetc.values(). Also simplify the if, change the alert and add a second array where to push the error:

```
var reservation  = ({NR, name, date, hour, gameRes})

let exist = allReservation.find(e => e.date=== reserva.date && e.hour=== reserva.hour && e.gameRes === reserva.gameRes);
  

  exist == undefined ? (allReservation.push(reservation), $("#alert-exito").fadeIn()) : (reservationError.push (reservation),$("#alert-error").fadeIn())
```

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about going through all reservations with a for loop and check whether it is in the array or not. At start, your array will be empty so first reservation will be added. The next will check out the current reservation array and if it exist, then do not add to it. There are many ways to check whether it is exist int the array or not. Here are some examples to show the methods:

```js
var num_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
var string_Array = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
var obj_array = [ { index: 1, value: "a" }, { index: 2, value: "b" }, { index: 2, value: "b" } ]

var num_ourArray = [];
var string_ourArray = [];
var obj_ourArray = [];

//loop through number array
$.each(num_array, function(k, v){

   //first way to check
   if ($.inArray(v, num_ourArray) == -1) //so if it's NOT in the array
   {
      num_ourArray.push(v)
   }
   
   //second way to check
   /*if (num_ourArray.indexOf(v) == -1) //so if it's NOT in the array
   {
      num_ourArray.push(v)
   }*/
})

console.log(num_ourArray)

//loop through string array
$.each(string_Array, function(k, v){

   //first way to check
   if ($.inArray(v, string_ourArray) == -1) //so if it's NOT in the array
   {
      string_ourArray.push(v)
   }
})

console.log(string_ourArray)

//loop through object array
$.each(obj_array, function(k, v){

   //first way to check
   if (!obj_ourArray.some(item => item.index === v.index)) //so if it's NOT in the array
   {
      obj_ourArray.push(v)
   }
})

console.log(obj_ourArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your logic:

```js
let allReservation = [];
var NR = 0

class Reservation
{
    constructor(date, hour, gameRes, nr, nameR)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.gameRes = gameRes;
        this.nr = nr;
        this.nameR = nameR;
    }

    get displayTitle()
    {
        return this.nr + ": " + this.nameR + this.date + this.hour + this.gameRes;
    }

    static is(a, b)
    {
        return a.date == b.date && a.hour == b.hour && a.gameRes == b.gameRes;
    }
}

const saveReserve = () => {
    var date= $("#date").val();    //These are the form inputs//
    var hour= $("#hour").val();
    var gameRes = $("#reserveG").val();
    NR++

   
    var reservation = new Reservation(date, hour, gameRes, NR, $("#nameR").val())
    let exist = allReservation.find(e=> Reservation.is(e, reservation));
    console.log(reservation, exist)
    
    if (exist == undefined) {
        allReservation.push(reservation);
        alert ("All good")
    }else{   
      alert ("Invalid, try again")
    }

    //nameR is the name input in the form//


    console.log (allReservation.map((reservation) => reservation.displayTitle))
    $("input").val('') 
}
$('button').click(saveReserve)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2021-08-05" id="date" />
<input type="number" id="hour" min="0" max="23" value="7" />
<input type="text" id="reserveG" value="A" />
<input type="text" id="nameR" value="B" />
<button>Send</button>
```